How to connect patroni nodes to etcd server?
I'm setting up a high availability PostgreSQL cluster using Patroni, and I want to utilize etcd as the distributed key-value store for configuration management. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly connect Patroni nodes to the etcd server.
Could someone provide guidance or a step-by-step approach on how to configure Patroni to interact with etcd for cluster coordination? Any insights into the configuration settings required or potential pitfalls to watch out for would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
